# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module xline.ko: Invalid module format

Tags: linux, module, kernel, fedora, insmod

I am trying to build a driver for a Heber X10i I/O controller on my Fedora 34 but I fail to insert the module into kernel, says "Invalid module format".

I followed all available tutorials/hints/Q&As but still no luck getting this running, am I experiencing some bug on Fedora side? Any perspective idea would be more than welcome.

Makefile:

```
xline-objs := xline_driver.o
obj-m := xline.o

KVERSION:=$(shell uname -r)
KDIR:= /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build
PWD:= $(shell pwd)

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

install: modules
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
    depmod -a

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

all: install
```

The compilation goes fine, result xline.ko is present and it's modinfo is as follows:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.12-200.fc34.x86_64/extra/xline.ko
author:         Heber Limited <http://www.heber.co.uk>
description:    Heber X-line Kernel Driver
license:        GPL
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FCEd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FCDd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FCCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FCBd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FCAd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FC9d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FC8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FC7d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FC4d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FC3d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FC6d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FB6p3FC5d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           xline
vermagic:       5.13.12-200.fc34.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Owner
sig_key:        34:F4:D8:C0:AB:0D:8D:1A:42:F8:BE:92:03:57:7E:7E:00:81:0E:06
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      0F:9F:01:85:BF:64:E8:49:03:2E:74:0D:4C:C4:DE:A8:9C:82:67:4A:
        20:41:24:F6:C3:73:41:00:6A:84:20:C9:37:94:CF:1B:95:43:C6:3D:
        E2:5C:B4:7F:28:D0:5F:DA:58:C2:54:CC:AD:D8:00:A5:CA:72:56:CF:
        FD:81:01:CC:3D:C9:CB:8C:C2:FF:80:DD:89:34:CB:5E:E6:15:BC:37:
        83:8C:4A:D1:44:A9:05:BE:B7:28:C6:6A:76:F3:11:F8:7A:07:CF:75:
        BC:13:6A:41:BE:A4:40:43:84:D9:2F:5F:F9:EC:77:E2:1E:B5:FA:18:
        8F:02:54:2E:0A:4C:33:41:52:2A:66:69:04:1A:58:C2:0C:17:27:C6:
        FA:3B:B6:35:B3:77:6D:F0:73:0A:BA:93:9E:89:FE:48:F8:11:23:BA:
        FF:7E:C8:3C:38:43:77:C0:74:31:89:65:70:C4:BB:17:5A:76:B5:C7:
        D3:74:B0:B9:11:BE:02:28:40:DE:07:5E:81:AE:17:E3:D0:65:81:71:
        B0:5D:0D:2F:65:41:3E:14:AE:D7:32:6A:2C:A4:FD:FE:A2:B9:C6:13:
        10:59:EC:EB:9D:B2:1A:DD:3C:F4:C7:3A:0B:48:CA:FC:81:0E:D1:88:
        18:A3:5E:69:F8:55:5E:2C:4B:34:14:DF:F0:E4:B6:E3
```

cat /proc/version:

```
Linux version 5.13.12-200.fc34.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.iad2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc (GCC) 11.2.1 20210728 (Red Hat 11.2.1-1), GNU ld version 2.35.2-4.fc34) #1 SMP Wed Aug 18 13:27:18 UTC 2021
```

gcc --version:

```
gcc (GCC) 11.2.1 20210728 (Red Hat 11.2.1-1)
```

ld --version:

```
GNU ld version 2.35.2-5.fc34
```

dmesg:

```
module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000000afa6010b, val ffffffffc19e9af2
```

yum list installed | grep kernel:

```
kernel.x86_64                                     5.11.12-300.fc34                     @anaconda
kernel.x86_64                                     5.13.10-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel.x86_64                                     5.13.12-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-core.x86_64                                5.11.12-300.fc34                     @anaconda
kernel-core.x86_64                                5.13.10-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-core.x86_64                                5.13.12-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-devel.x86_64                               5.13.10-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-devel.x86_64                               5.13.12-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-headers.x86_64                             5.13.3-200.fc34                      @updates
kernel-modules.x86_64                             5.11.12-300.fc34                     @anaconda
kernel-modules.x86_64                             5.13.10-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-modules.x86_64                             5.13.12-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-modules-extra.x86_64                       5.11.12-300.fc34                     @anaconda
kernel-modules-extra.x86_64                       5.13.10-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-modules-extra.x86_64                       5.13.12-200.fc34                     @updates
kernel-tools.x86_64                               5.13.6-200.fc34                      @updates
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64                          5.13.6-200.fc34                      @updates
```

I tried to find kernel-headers 5.13.12 but no success.

One remark: the driver code xline_driver.c was outdated, so I fixed it - but that should be an executable problem (if any).

EDIT: whole procedure with the code works on linux-mint (ubuntu) 5.4.0-74-generic (why not on fedora?)

Comment: You already have the "kernel-headers 5.13.12" .... provided by the package `kernel-devel-5.13.12-200.fc34` .

Comment: Don't you have "module verification failed" error **above** the one you show? As in that question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582637/module-x86-modules-skipping-invalid-relocation-target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the module is signed correctly, you can see that also in the modinfo output, no other messages in dmesg are present.

Comment: Anyone also experiencing this problem, update to kernel version 5.13.13-200.fc34.x86_64 solved the actual problem, yet still the answer persists, what was wrong